# Disable horizontal scroll bar in list view

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a list view where I want to disable the horizontal scroll bar.

Basically, I know none of my data will exceed the width of the single column, but if enough entries get added to the list view, the vertical scroll bar pops up, reducing the width available, making the horizontal scroll bar pop up.

<strike>I was thinking about some how catching a message right before the vertical scroll bar gets added, and then re-sizing the column to make enough room, but I don't know what message I would need to catch to do this.</strike>

**EDIT:**
Does anyone know if there is a message sent after an item in a list view is deleted? `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` appeared to only be sent after an item is added. And `LVN_DELETEITEM` only before an item is deleted.

Comment: Why don't you just keep the width of the last column limited? Then you know for sure the horizontal scroll bar won't show up...

Comment: Because I only have a single column, and the column separator looks ugly. And for several reasons, it has to be in report mode.

Comment: Maybe you can check if the first OR the last item is not visible using `LVM_ISITEMVISIBLE`. Then you should reduce the width of the column. And check that every time you add an item or on resizing.

Comment: Hmm that might work better then my current solution, I'll play around with it and see what I come up with.

Comment: Do you know if there a message sent after an item is deleted? `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` appeared to only be sent after an item is added. And `LVN_DELETEITEM` only before an item is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I worked out one solution.
There is a bug though, if I only remove one item it doesn't resize the column.

```
case LVN_DELETEITEM:
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW listView = (LPNMLISTVIEW) lParam;

    // After an item is deleted,
    // if there is not a vertical scroll bar and GWL_USERDATA is TRUE,
    // resize the column back to normal.
    if (!(GetWindowLong(listView->hdr.hwndFrom, GWL_STYLE) & WS_VSCROLL) &&
          GetWindowLong(listView->hdr.hwndFrom, GWL_USERDATA) == TRUE)
    {
        const int ColWidth = ListView_GetColumnWidth(listView->hdr.hwndFrom, 0);
        ListView_SetColumnWidth(listView->hdr.hwndFrom, 0, ColWidth + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL));
        SetWindowLong(listView->hdr.hwndFrom, GWL_USERDATA, FALSE);
    }

    break;
}

case LVN_ITEMCHANGED:
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW listView = (LPNMLISTVIEW) lParam;

    // After an item is added, if there is a horizontal scrollbar,
    // resize the column and set GWL_USERDATA to TRUE.
    if (GetWindowLong(listView->hdr.hwndFrom, GWL_STYLE) & WS_HSCROLL)
    {
        const int ColWidth = ListView_GetColumnWidth(listView->hdr.hwndFrom, 0);
        ListView_SetColumnWidth(listView->hdr.hwndFrom, 0, ColWidth - GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL));
        SetWindowLong(listView->hdr.hwndFrom, GWL_USERDATA, TRUE);
    }

    break;
}
```

I'd still love to see a better solution, but this works for now.

Comment: You could also watch for WM_STYLECHANGED messages and resize the column whenever WS_VSCROLL changes. I don't think there's any way around the manual resizing of the column however.

Answer (score 2):

You could send the message: LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH to the listview with cx param set to LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER

Comment: Please can you be more specific?